# How to avoid opening a workbook referenced in vlookup between 3 workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

**Situation:**
I have three excel workbooks of which `Workbook1` and `Workbook2` contain my data. In `Workbook3` there is a `VLOOKUP` which references to the data in `Workbook1` and `Workbook2`.
All of that works fine.

**Problem:**
When I save and close all workbooks and reopen `Workbook3` only, the cells containing the `VLOOKUP` will only show `#NV` until I open `Workbook1` and `Workbook2` too.

**Question:**
Is it possible to avoid opening the data containing sheet everytime I open the referencing sheet? If yes, how do I achieve this?

**Solution:**
The referenced worksheets used the old `.xls`format. It seems as old workbooks need to be opened. After saving them as `.xlsx`the problem did not exist any longer.

Comment: Changed `Sheets` to `Workbooks` wich is a totally different situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the data from a referenced workbook with `VLOOKUP` <strike>requires said workbook to be opened too.
So no, it is not possible to avoid opening all referenced sheets too.</strike>
does **not** require the workbooks to be open if they are saved in the `.xlsx` format. However, if the workbooks use the old `.xls`format they need to be opened.

As an alternative it is possible to import data from a closed workbook into another workbook using `VBA`. `VLOOKUP`is then possible on the imported data.

Another way with `VBA`is to automatically open all referenced sheets on startup, updating all references and closing said workbooks again using the following code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Links
Dim i%
Links = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
If Not IsEmpty(Links) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(Links)
      Workbooks.Open Links(i), 0
    Next i
Else
End If
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
For Each w In Workbooks
If w.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
    w.Close savechanges:=False
End If
Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't believe this to be the case, and I don't believe VBA is necessary. See my answer above. You can update links to a closed workbook without opening them.

Comment: @Kyle As I just learned: Yes you are right **if** the workbook use the new format `.xlsx`. Old workbooks with `.xls`however have to be opened.
I edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Data > Connections > Edit Links > Update Values`. This will give you the current values from the workbook without opening it. You can also set links to automatically update, although this will slow opening if a lot of links are present. This method only works if the files linked are .xlsx, not .xls.

Comment: This feature works fine with simple links like `='path\to\file\[workbook.xls]worksheet'!$C$18`
But with  `VLOOKUP('path\to\file\[workbook.xls]worksheet'!$C$18; 'path\to\file\[workbook2.xls]worksheet2'!$A$1:$B$400; 2; FALSE)` it wont. In this case it will only set the values to `#NV`

Comment: Good to know. I will edit my response so that folks looking to update links in .xlsx files know there is another option.